# Order by multiple properties using Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

How can I order my Realm results using multiple properties?

I'm sorting them first using one property like this:

```
allShows = Show.allObjects().sortedResultsUsingProperty("dateStart", ascending: true)
```

But now I also want to do a secondary sort by another property "timeStart". I tried like this:

```
allShows = Show.allObjects().sortedResultsUsingProperty("dateStart", ascending: true).sortedResultsUsingProperty("timeStart", ascending: true)
```

This will just make the results sorted only by the second property. Please help.

Answer (score 43):

In RealmSwift we can write multiple properties like this:

```
let sortProperties = [SortDescriptor(property: "dateStart", ascending: true), SortDescriptor(property: "timeStart", ascending: true)]
allShowsByDate = Realm().objects(MyObjectType).sorted(sortProperties)
```

If you want to use more properties,you can add values of `SortDescriptor()` to the array.

Comment: How can i do multiple sorting with custom function?

Comment: @TomSawyer You can use this method sort({ (first, second) -> Bool in
      if first.startDate.compare( second.startDate ) == .Ascending {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    })

Comment: @AIG If there is nested optional type property, how we will sort it.

Comment: In Swift 4 you now have to use `.sorted(by: sortProperties)`.

Answer (score 17):

Figured it out like this:

```
let sortProperties = [RLMSortDescriptor(property: "dateStart", ascending: true), RLMSortDescriptor(property: "timeStart", ascending: true)]
allShowsByDate = Show.allObjects().sortedResultsUsingDescriptors(sortProperties)
```

Comment: It looks like they refactored RLMSortDescriptor to SortDescriptor

Comment: any idea how to implement this in RealmSwift ?

Comment: what if the property is an object ?

Answer (score 8):

Updated for Swift 4 syntax

```
let sortProperties = [SortDescriptor(keyPath: "queue"), SortDescriptor(keyPath: "name")]
let dogList = realm.objects(Dog.self).sorted(by: sortProperties)
```

Comment: It would make sense that the realm object model gives us something like Dog.fields.queue.name etc to avoid "stringly" code, given the fields are defined.

Answer (score 3):

This is how to do it as of Realm 2.5

```
      dataArray = try! Realm().objects(Book.self)
        .sorted( by: [SortDescriptor(keyPath: "Author", ascending: true), SortDescriptor(keyPath: "Title", ascending: true)] )
```

Answer (score 1):

i have found a solution.

```
var dataSource: Results<DLVCasting>! = nil
let realm = try! Realm()
let sortDescriptors = [SortDescriptor(property: "someValue", ascending: false)]
dataSource = realm.objects(MyClass.self).sorted(sortDescriptors);
dataSource = dataSource.sorted("anotherValue", ascending: false)
```

But if you put more than one sort descripton in array like example below

```
let sortDescriptors = [SortDescriptor(property: "someValue", ascending: false),SortDescriptor(property: "someValue", ascending: false)]
```

this won't work. I really don't understand why.

Comment: If I put more than one sort description this won't work also. I really don't understand why also.