# Realm results sort on multiple properties ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, realm

I have been trying to sort RLMResults by 2 properties, 1st is sort value and 2nd is name, but no luck.
I am getting wrong results when I try to sort with 2 properties.

What I want is I want to sort results using sort value and then alphabetically.

```
self.allTasks = [[[Task allObjects]
                 sortedResultsUsingProperty:@"priorityLevelSortValue" ascending:YES]
                 sortedResultsUsingProperty:@"taskName" ascending:YES];
```

Any help would be much appreciable.

Thank you.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27366803) help? It's in Swift but should be easy to translate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`-[RLMResults sortedResultsUsingDescriptors:]`](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMResults.html#/c:objc(cs)RLMResults(im)sortedResultsUsingDescriptors:) to sort by multiple properties:

```
[[Task allObjects] sortedResultsUsingDescriptors:@[
    [RLMSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithProperty:@"priorityLevelSortValue" ascending:YES],
    [RLMSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithProperty:@"taskName" ascending:YES]
]];
```